# how to upload ipa builds to apple testflight

Tags: windows, file-upload, testflight, ipa

I need upload ipa builds to the apple testflight from windows. On mac there are no problem with it because you can do it from XCODE or from transporter tool for mac.

How to do it on windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

As TestFlight is owned by Apple nowadays, only TestFlight from AppStore and Visual Studio for Mac have that capability. So, the only way to have them running inside a Windows Physical PC is through a Virtual Machine. Here are 2 useful links:

[Using TestFlight to Distribute Xamarin.iOS Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/testflight?tabs=macos)

[How to Install macOS High Sierra in VirtualBox on Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/289594/how-to-install-macos-sierra-in-virtualbox-on-windows-10/)

I hope you find them useful.